# Why is there such a long delay between rep on the site, and rep on the chat?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, privileges

So, recently there was a huge confusion with my age, and my acount was deleted. read about that [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17/20-21#message-21331012), but after I cleared it up with Jon, there, I gave him my posts, and whatever I could find was restored, but I have been trying to reenable by chat presence, and I see the need 20 rep message.
[image]
but my rep says:
[image]

My question: Why after alot of rep is restored in a short period, is there such a long delay between the main site, and the meta/chat?